# Delete std::thread after calling join?

Tags: c++, multithreading, c++11, std, stdthread

I have some code that dynamically allocates a new `std::thread` from the C++11 `<thread>` header, like this:

```
std::thread *th = new thread( /* my args */);
```

Some time later, I call join:

```
th->join();
```

Since I dynamically allocated the thread, do I also need to call `delete th;` to free the memory? If I do, do I still need to call `join()` first?

Comment: I think you do. But why not use shared_ptr since you are using C++11?

Comment: I learned C++ before C++11 came out and am still learning about all the new stuff. Didn't think to use shared_ptr :)

Comment: or better, use `std::unique_ptr`, unless you really need shared ownership. Heaving a unique owner also makes it clear who is responsible for the joining

Answer (score 21, accepted):

To avoid memory leaks, you need to both: `join` a running thread, and make sure it is destructed/deleted (let it go out of scope for stack-allocated `std::threads` or explicitly call delete for `std::thread*`).

See [thread::~thread](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/thread/thread/~thread) in cppreference:

> A thread object does not have an associated thread (and is safe to destroy) after:
>
> - it was default-constructed
> - it was moved from
> - join() has been called
> - detach() has been called

A non-joined thread, therefore, cannot be safely destructed.

A `join()`ed `std::thread` will still occupy some memory. Therefore you need to make sure it is properly deallocated if it is on the heap.

Answer (score 6):

Yes you have to call `join` before destroying the thread object. If the destructor for a `std::thread` object that is joinable (i.e. if [`joinable`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/thread/thread/joinable) returns true) is called, it will call `std::terminate`. Therefore, you have to call `join` before destroying the thread, whether by calling delete (for threads on the heap) or by it being destroyed normally.

To prevent a memory leak you have to call delete, as with any other heap allocated variable.

See [here](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/thread/thread) for more information on `std::thread`.